# Regex for specific wording in string

Tags: android, regex, string

I am comparing versions numbers delivered as a string.

I need to detect whether a version is a **beta** release or not, I want to check if **beta**, **build** or **b** is included in the last part of the version and I am trying to do this with a regex.

So far it works but as soon as there is a space in the version part it doesn`t.

Maybe someone has a better idea?

My regex so far:

```
(\d+)(beta|build|b(\d*))?
```

String examples:

v1.23beta125 --> ok

v1.25.458 beta 129 --> not recognized

Sample code:

```
private Boolean getBeta(String str) {

        boolean version = false;
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)(beta|build|b(\\d*))?");

        Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

        if (!m.find()) {

            return version;

        } else
            version = true;

        return version;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use the following regex that is more restrictive:

```
v?\s*(\d+(\.\d*)*)+\s*(beta|build|b)\s*(\d+)
```

Tested on **regex101**: https://regex101.com/r/oLoVN3/2

you need to add a backslash `\` for before each backslash `\` in order to use it in your code.

Comment: Thx Allan, that gave me a hind and it works.

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You can use space as optional(0 or more)

Try this regex:

```
(beta|build|b)\s*(\d+)
```

Answer (score 0):

I mean, all you want is just to find whether there is a `b`, `beta` or `build` in the version string, right? `contains` can do that. You don't need regexes :)

Well, you can also use this regex

```
build|beta|b
```

Check if `find` returns true.

You might also want to turn on case-insensitive option.